# how to find the biggest sum in a row of a two dimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, sum

I found some answers related to this problem already, but I don't really get how they work. I need to find the biggest sum of each row of a two dimensional and print it out, but don't print any of the other sums out. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{

    int v[3][5]; // 3 rows, then 5 columns
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
            cin >> v[i][j];

        }
    }
    //test reading value
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
                cout << v[i][j];
                if (i!=4)
                    cout << ' ';

            }
            cout << '\n';
        }
    //solve it
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        int sum = 0;
                for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
                    sum += v[i][j];
                }
                cout << sum << '\n';
            }
    return 0;
}
```

This code right now prints out the sum of each row in the 2D array, but I need my program to print out just the biggest sum of the rows. This is the only problem I have right now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: I need to get the biggest sum of each row.

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself?

Comment: @OMGtechy Yes, I have. This is what I have got so far. This is just like the first step of my problem. I still have one more question to ask.

Comment: @OMGtechy How do I get out of a question ban since I got it for this question.

Comment: You're probably asking too many questions too quickly. You must simply wait until you are able to ask more; the ban is there for a reason not to be gotten around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by keeping track of the largest sum computed for each row of the array.

```
//solve it
int largestSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
    {
        sum += v[i][j];
    }
    // check to see if we have computed a new larger sum and save it if we have.
    if (sum > largestSum)
    {
        largestSum = sum;
    }
}
cout << "largest sum: " << largestSum << '\n';
```

Alternatively if you are allowed to use other components in the C++ Standard library you can use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) to calculate the sum instead of using an inner look, and [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) to determine the largest sum between current and previously calculated sum.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

//solve it
int largestSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    int sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(v[i]), std::end(v[i]), 0);
    largestSum = std::max(sum, largestSum);
}
cout << "largest sum: " << largestSum << '\n';
```

Comment: or even use `std::max`

Comment: @OMGtechy Yes, `std::max` would be groovy but questions like this are typically homework related and use of the standard library is limited.

Comment: Fair enough :) might be worth adding an "if you can use the standard library" section

Comment: @OMGtechy Updated with example using `std::accumulate` and `std::max`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious do you know why this question caused me to be banned from posting new questions? I got banned from posting new questions. How do you fix this?

Comment: No sorry I do not. Posting bans are based on posting history so if you have posted and deleted a few questions and/or had a certain number of previous posts closed or downvoted enough that could explain the ban.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the shortest solution I could come up with, and also correctly handling negative sums (C++11):

```
int maxSum = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
for (const auto& row : v)
   maxSum = std::max(maxSum, std::accumulate(std::begin(row), std::end(row), 0));
std::cout << maxSum << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int biggestSum = 0;

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    int currentSum = 0;      // sum of values in this row
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
            currentSum += v[i][j];
    }
  if ( currentSum > biggestSum) biggestSum = currentSum;  // we have new max
}

cout << biggestSum << '\n';
```